# Creating a user, getting not-acceptable (406)

Tags: java, android, debugging, xmpp, smack

I'm using asmack XMPP with android code. I'm logging-in the XMPP server just fine, but the problem occurs when I'm trying to create a new user. What I want to achieve is the following:

1. Login with administrator.
2. Create a new user.
3. Logout from administrator.
4. Login as a newly craeted user.
5. Do some actions - play the game.
6. Delete the newly created user.

This allows the players to not register, since the registration is handled automatically and also allows users to choose whatever name is still available at a current time.

The current code is the following:

```
  public void create_user(String username, String password) {
    try {
      connection.login("user", "pass");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (connection.isAuthenticated()) {
      AccountManager manager = connection.getAccountManager();
      try {
        manager.createAccount(username, password);
      } catch (XMPPException e) {
        Log.w("[create_user] Cannot create new user: XMPP Exception.", "0");
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.w("[create_user] Cannot create new user: not logged in.", "0");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  }
```

The login part of the code is sucessful. The second part of the code is not. I'm receiving the following error:

```
W/[create_user] Cannot create new user: XMPP Exception.( 1525): 0
W/System.err( 1525): not-acceptable(406)
W/System.err( 1525):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager.java:246)
W/System.err( 1525):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager.java:207)
W/System.err( 1525):    at company.games.boxer.XMPPManager.create_user(XMPPManager.java:81)
W/System.err( 1525):    at company.games.boxer.XMPPManager.xmpp_login(XMPPManager.java:113)
W/System.err( 1525):    at company.games.boxer.XMPPClient.onCreate(XMPPClient.java:19)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/System.err( 1525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
W/System.err( 1525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 1525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err( 1525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
W/System.err( 1525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
W/System.err( 1525):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can somebody tell me why? I have sufficient permissions to create users, since I'm logging in as user:pass (which is an administrator of the XMPP server).

Comment: *ahem* … ah … you're not planning to *ship* this code with the *server admin* user name and password in the `apk`, are you … ?

Comment: Glad I could help, and as BRPocock says, you should maybe ask the server to either send a username/password you can log in with, or move the registration to the server and let it return the login credentials for the current user rather than putting the admin password in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in the [smack docs](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html#createAccount%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), it here says that

> The server may require a number of extra account attributes such as an
>   email address and phone number.

This is consistent with the registration error in [XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html#usecases-register) ('example 7. Host Informs Entity of Failed Registration (Some Required Information Not Provided)').
You should check the required attributes with [`getAccountAttributes()`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html#getAccountAttributes%28%29), as well as enable the smack debugger to see what data is sent/received to make sure you have all the needed tags.

I hope this helps with the problem.

Comment: Hi. This fixed it:
        HashMap<String, String> attr = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attr.put("username", username);
        attr.put("password", password);
        manager.createAccount(username, password, attr);
But the username and password are already provided when calling createAccount(). I don't know why I had to specify them twice. Anyway it works.